# How to get available WIFI SSID and signal stength in c language

Tags: android, c, android-wifi, android-4.4-kitkat, native-code

I want to get the list of SSID and the signal stregth of the available WIFI near my android device through my c programming. I search got this information but I didn't get any information for it. 
If anybody knows how to get this from a c program please share the method.

Thanks 
Amit

Comment: Use [JNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and the android API.

Comment: JNI will be called from java application. But I wanted to develop a complete native library which will get the available wifi information. I will not interact any java application to get this information. Please tell me the API will I can use from my c program to get this information in android.

Comment: What's the reason to use C?

Comment: I am developing 1 driver in that driver I need this information. So I can't just java for it. I need to use C only.

Answer (score 0):

On common linux desktop systems you use tools like iw, iwlist or iwconfig. On android these tools are not available by default. [There is a port for android](https://github.com/nvamelichev/wireless-tools-android).